# AD B2C default signup-sign-in flow returns the "emails" claim with value type string instead of array

Tags: asp.net-core, active-directory, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am writing .Net Core API code that examines the value of the AD B2C built-in `emails` claim.  I'm expecting this claim to show up on the `ClaimsPrincipal` as an `IList<string>` or similar, but it is instead of type `string`.

The `Email Addresses claim` is selected in the Azure portal and shows a data type of `StringCollection` and the `emails` claim appears on the `ClaimsPrincipal` but it is of type `string`.  The data I am working with only has a single email address per user so I'm not sure what would happen if there were multiple email addresses.

I understand why AD returns an `emails` claim (plural) rather than an `email` claim (singular) so why is the `emails` claim value a string (the user's email address) instead of an array containing that single email address?

This:

```
emails: 'email@somedomain.com'
```

Instead of this:

```
emails: ['email@somedomain.com']
```

I'm currently on .NET Core 3.1

Updated to .NET 6 and I still experience the same thing.  Am I missing a setting in AD or elsewhere?  Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @Beau - No.  I put a check in the code to deal with the value either way (array or string).

Answer (score 0):

When i tried i got the alternate email address in stringCollection format.

[image]

Please try to raise a support request if two or more mails when added are not reflecting in the emails claim else its not an issue AFAIK.